# How to instantiate the repository that uses ninject in a unit test

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, repository, ninject

I have a repository like:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
   private readonly IContext _db;

   public Repository(IContext context)
   {
      _db =context;
   }

   ...
```

In Global.asax I have setup the ninject as:

```
kernel.Bind<IContext>().To<Context>();
```

This is working fine in the app probably because I'm explicity instantiating by calling the constructor with a paramater. There are problems in the unit tests however.

Then in a unit test I have:

```
var mockUnitOfWork = new Mock<UnitOfWork>();

var mockProjectApprovalRepository = new Mock<Repository<ProjectApproval>>();

mockUnitOfWork.Setup(x => x.ProjectApprovalRepository).Returns(mockProjectApprovalRepository.Object);
```

On this last line I get the error:

Can not instantiate proxy of class: MyNamespace.Repository Could not find a parameterless constructor.

I'm confused by this because I thought the point of Ninject was I didn't need to specify a parameterless constructor. Shouldn't ninject have instantiated a Context and used the constructor with one parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `new Mock<Repository<ProjectApproval>>()`, you're asking Moq to construct the object. If you asked Ninject to construct it, it would do it.

Ninject doesn't magically step in wherever construction happens - `new` is still `new`.

In this case, you can use an overload of the `Mock` constructor wherein you specify extra args.

Note that its generally accepted that Ninject shouldnt be anywhere near anything remotely close to the any common definition of the term Unit Test.